# Topological sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I am learning algorithms in graphs.  I have implemented topological sort using Java. Kindly review my code and provide me with feedback.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;



public class TopologicalSortGraph {

    /**
     *  This Topological Sort implementation takes the example graph in 
     *  Version 1: implementation with unweighted
     *  Assumption : Graph is directed 
     */
    TopologicalSortGraph Graph = new TopologicalSortGraph();
    //public LinkedList<Node> nodes  = new LinkedList<Node>();

    public static void  topologicalSort(Graph graph) {
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
        int vertexProcessesCtr = 0;
        for(Node m : graph.nodes){
            if(m.inDegree==0){
                ++vertexProcessesCtr;
                q.add(m);
                System.out.println(m.data);
            }
        }
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            Node m = q.poll();

            //System.out.println(m.data);
            for(Node child : m.AdjacenctNode){
                --child.inDegree;
                if(child.inDegree==0){
                    q.add(child);
                    ++vertexProcessesCtr;
                    System.out.println(child.data);
                }
            }

        }
        if(vertexProcessesCtr > graph.vertices) {
            System.out.println();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph g= new Graph();
        g.vertices=8;

    Node TEN = new Node("10");
    Node ELEVEN = new Node("11");
    Node TWO = new Node("2");
    Node THREE = new Node("3");
    Node FIVE = new Node("5");
    Node SEVEN = new Node("7");
    Node EIGHT = new Node("8");
    Node NINE = new Node("9");

    SEVEN.AdjacenctNode.add(ELEVEN);
    ELEVEN.inDegree++;
    SEVEN.AdjacenctNode.add(EIGHT);
    EIGHT.inDegree++;
    FIVE.AdjacenctNode.add(ELEVEN);
    ELEVEN.inDegree++;
    THREE.AdjacenctNode.add(EIGHT);
    EIGHT.inDegree++;
    THREE.AdjacenctNode.add(TEN);
    TEN.inDegree++;
    ELEVEN.AdjacenctNode.add(TEN);
    TEN.inDegree++;
    ELEVEN.AdjacenctNode.add(TWO);
    TWO.inDegree++;
    ELEVEN.AdjacenctNode.add(NINE);
    NINE.inDegree++;    
    EIGHT.AdjacenctNode.add(NINE);
    NINE.inDegree++;    

    g.nodes.add(TWO);
    g.nodes.add(THREE);
    g.nodes.add(FIVE);
    g.nodes.add(SEVEN);
    g.nodes.add(EIGHT);
    g.nodes.add(NINE);


    System.out.println("Now calling the topologial sorts");

    topologicalSort(g);



    }
}
```

Graph class:

```
class Graph {
    public int vertices;
    LinkedList<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
}
```

Node Class:

```
class Node {
    public String data;
    public int dist;
    public int inDegree;
    LinkedList<Node> AdjacenctNode = new LinkedList<Node>( );

    public void addAdjNode(final Node Child){
        AdjacenctNode.add(Child);
        Child.inDegree++;
    }

    public Node(String data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class Graph {
    public int vertices;
    LinkedList<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
}
```

### `Graph`

`Graph`, as other data structures in general, should be declared 
`public`. Because you want them to be able to be used outside of the 
package they are declared in.

`nodes`, `vertices` should be `private` so that you *can* know that they 
are not changed outside the `Graph` class.

`nodes` should not be a `LinkedList`. You must depend on abstractions as 
much as possible. You should prefer `interface`s such as `List` over 
specific implementations `LinkedList`.

Nodes of a graph is not a `List`, it is a `Set`. A standard graph cannot 
have multiple copies of a node. You should prefer a `Set` to represent a 
set unless you have a good reason.

### `Node`

All of the above points also apply to `Node`. Apart from those:

`AdjacenctNode` should be named `adjacentNode` by Java naming 
convention.

Feel free to remove parameterless call to `super();`, although Eclipse 
adds it by default, it's just noise.

### `TopologicalSortGraph`

Remove unused code :

```
TopologicalSortGraph Graph = new TopologicalSortGraph();
```

Always remove commented code. If you need to see previous versions of a 
code use a version control system. :

```
//public LinkedList<Node> nodes  = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

Do not put more than one space between tokens, use autoformat of your 
IDE to fix formatting after changing a piece of code:

```
public static void  topologicalSort(Graph graph) {
```

The snippets :

```
if(child.inDegree==0){
    q.add(child);
    ++vertexProcessesCtr;
    System.out.println(child.data);
}
```

and

```
if(m.inDegree==0){
    ++vertexProcessesCtr;
    q.add(m);
    System.out.println(m.data);
}
```

are duplicates. They should be extracted to a `private` method. You are 
missing some kind of abstraction there.

You are changing the internals of an object passed in as a parameter: 
`--child.inDegree;` I do not expect my graph to change after I ask to 
see its nodes printed in topological order. What if I want to print 
them again?

You are mixing the calculation and the printing out of the calculation result, 
I do not expect to see `println`s in a method implementing an algorithm:

`System.out.println( .... );`

What if I want the result to be printed somewhere other than `System.out`? 
What if I do not want the result to be printed at all and want it to be 
used as an intermediate step in a bigger calculation instead?

You probably want to return a `List<Node>` from a topological sort 
algorithm. `List` is the standard return type when you are sorting some 
collection, that is when the result is a collection whose order is 
important. You can then print that list as many times as you want or 
pass it as a parameter to wherever you like.

### `public static void main(String[] args) {`

You should separate test code from your main code. If your actual class 
is named `TopologicalSortGraph` put your test code in 
`TopologicalSortGraphTest`.

Use de facto standard `JUnit` so that instead of one big `main` you can 
have many small tests. You can run any one of them or all of them easily 
from within your IDE or from the command line.

You should try to separate the test code into separate source 
directories or even into separate projects. Your implementation code 
should not need or know about your test code to compile.

Another spacing (indentation) problem :

```
Node TEN = new Node("10");
```

Your code should align well. So that it reads neatly top to bottom and 
scopes in it are easily identified.

`TEN` should be `ten` by Java naming convention.

Instead of these two you should use your `addAdjNode` method instead:

```
SEVEN.AdjacenctNode.add(ELEVEN);
ELEVEN.inDegree++;
```

Also access chains like `node.AdjacenctNode.add(otherNode)` or `x.y.z` 
are usually a sign that your encapsulation is not good enough. In this 
case you are modifying a collection of one class from another class. 
It's a problem waiting to happen. Same encapsulation problem is present 
in `ELEVEN.inDegree++`, too.

The root problem here is adjacency is a property of the graph -Remember 
`G = (V, E)` from school?- and not of the nodes themselves. Instead of 
`node.addAdjNode(otherNode)`, you should use a method like 
`graph.addEdge(node, otherNode)`.

Same problem also exists here: `g.nodes.add(TWO);` You should have a
`Graph.addNode(node)` method instead.

Coming back to `G = (V, E)`; it says, if you listen carefully, you need 
a set of vertices and a set of edges to have a graph and should not add 
nodes one by one. Ideally, `Graph` would have a constructor like this 
`public Graph(Set<Node> vertices, Set<Edge> edges)`.